# return empty result for a nested bool query on fields that don't have data

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm doing the following query:
[image]

the `ns.ns` field has configured (has both mapping and setting set up successfully) but there is no source data for this field. and I get empty result returned from ElasticSearch. is that right? I mean without data this query would return empty result, is that correct? Still learning ES and thanks for the help.

Comment: did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The `ns.ns` field has configured (has both mapping and setting set up
> successfully) but there is no source data for this field. and I get
> empty result returned from ElasticSearch. is that right?
> without data this query would return an empty result, is that correct?

As you have mentioned above that the `ns` field is mapped as type `nested`, therefore when you hit the search query you will not get `"index_not_found_exception"`, since the index already exists.

The [search API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-search.html#search-search) returns search hits that match the query defined in the request.
When you hit the search query, mentioned in the question above, the following response is there:

```
 {
    "took": 17,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 0,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    }
}
```

The response provides the following information about the [search request](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/getting-started-search.html#getting-started-search):

> took – how long it took Elasticsearch to run the query, in
> milliseconds
>
> timed_out – whether or not the search request timed out
>
> _shards – how many shards were searched and a breakdown of how many shards succeeded, failed, or were skipped.
>
> max_score – the score of the most relevant document found
>
> hits.total.value - how many matching documents were found

The `hits.hits` above returns a blank array(`[]`), `hits.hits` is an array of found documents that meet your search query. As here no documents are indexed, therefore no documents are matched when a search query is hit.

Refer to this ES documentation, to know more about [how scoring works in ES](https://qbox.io/blog/practical-guide-elasticsearch-scoring-relevancy)

> In the above response `max_score` value is `NULL`, the _score in
> Elasticsearch is a way of determining how relevant a match is to the
> query.